# C++ get string between two delimiters and replace it

Tags: c++, string, delimiter

I want to replace a substring in a string with something that depends on the substring between to delimiters. Little example:

I got the string

```
The result is __--__3__--__.
```

and a function

```
int square(int x): { return x*x };
```

Now I want to output just the string with the result without delimiters, so:

```
The result is 9.
```

I already tried several algorithms but none of them worked yet.
Best regard

My best attempt to far:

```
    const std::string emptyString = "";
std::string ExtractString(std::string source, std::string start, std::string end)
{
    std::size_t startIndex = source.find(start);

    // If the starting delimiter is not found on the string
    // stop the process, you're done!
    //
    if (startIndex == std::string::npos)
    {
        return emptyString;
    }

    // Adding the length of the delimiter to our starting index
    // this will move us to the beginning of our sub-string.
    //
    startIndex += start.length();

    // Looking for the end delimiter
    //
    std::string::size_type endIndex = source.find(end, startIndex);

    // Returning the substring between the start index and
    // the end index. If the endindex is invalid then the
    // returned value is empty string.
    return source.substr(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
}

int square(int x): { return x*x };

int main() {
    std::string str = "The result is __--__3__--__.";
    std::string foundNum = ExtractString(str, "__--__", "__--__");
    int foundNumInt = atoi(foundNum.c_str());
    int result = square(foundNumInt);
    std::string toReplace = "__--__";
    toReplace.append(foundNumInt);
    toReplace.append("__--__");
    str.replace(str.begin(), str.end(), toReplace, result);
}
```

The Question is: How to take the first string given ( `The result is __--__<number>__--__.`>, get the number from it, preform a function on that number, and then end with a string that looks like this `The result is <number squared>`.

Comment: Just use `std::regex` Anyway you did not show any effort and this seem to be a homework.

Comment: what is the purpose of the `The result is __--__3__--__.` like what do the blank spots mean? Im not exactly what you want to replace and what you are looking to do...

Comment: @CU_dev Assume that I get an input from a server with this message. I want to replace the substring "__ -__3__--__" with the result of the function call square(3) (sorry for bold characters, that's stackoverflow's formatting)

Comment: so you want to find the 3 and then replace everything after `is` with the answer?

Comment: yeah, that's it pretty much

Comment: Please edit your post with your best effort that "didn't work".  Post code as text, no screen snapshots, no links to screen snapshots or other sites.

Comment: This is [hilarious](https://imgur.com/a/LuTRA4D) ))

Comment: It'd be nice if the code was actually C++ and not something else. **Please show the code you tried**.

Comment: Yeah, I just edited the post

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to take the first string, find the number. I then just squared the number, but you could plug that into your own function of you wanted to.

```
std::string s = "The result is __--__3__--__.";
std::regex r( "[0-9]+");
std::smatch m;

//
std::sregex_iterator iter(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
std::sregex_iterator end;
std::string value;
//
int index = 0;
while (iter != end)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < iter->size(); ++i)
    {
        value = (*iter)[i];
    }
    ++iter;
    index++;
}

int num = stoi(value);

int answer = num*num;

s = s.substr(0, s.find('_'));
s = s + " " + std::to_string(answer);

std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `std::string::find`?

```
const std::string example_data = "The result is __--__3__--__.";
static const char text_to_find[] = "__--__";
const std::string::size_type start_position = example_data.find(text_to_find);
if (start_position != std::string::npos)
{
  const std::string::size_type replacement_start_position = start_position + sizeof(text_to_find) - 1;
  if (replacement_start_position < example_data.length())
  {
    // Perform replacement
  }
}
```

The "sizeof(text_to_find) - 1" returns the length of the text, without counting the terminating nul character.

To skip past the number, you could do something like:

```
const std::string after_number_position = example_data.find(replacement_start_position, "_");
```

The substring between `replacement_start_position` and `after_number_position` will contain your number.  You can use a variety of functions to convert the substring to a number.

See also `std::ostringstream` for converting numbers to text.

**Edit 1:**
*Corrected declaration of `replacement_start_position`.*

Comment: You should probably add a warning with the `sizeof` since it commonly gets misused.

Comment: Yeah I also tried something like this. The problem is, that the 3 can even be a 10 or 100. Although the text before the __--__3__--__ could be changed. In Python this would be so super easy..

Comment: If you notice, the code I posted searches for the key characters after the number.  This eliminates the need to run a numeric parser on the text.  You can also put the substring into `std::istringstream` to read in the number.

Comment: Bad compiler.  Convert all the `std::string::size_type` to `size_t`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's just a typo. You missed `::size_type` inside the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You must need these functions(for c++17, much faster):

```
auto replace_all
(std::string str, std::string_view from, std::string_view to) noexcept -> decltype(str) {
    unsigned start_pos{ 0 };

    while ((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length();
    }
    return str;
}

auto remove_all
(std::string str, std::string_view from) noexcept -> decltype(str) {
    return replace_all(str, from, "");
}
```

and for later versions:

```
std::string replace_all
(std::string str, std::string from, std::string to) noexcept {
    unsigned start_pos{ 0 };

    while ((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length();
    }
    return str;
}

std::string remove_all
(std::string str, std::string from) noexcept {
    return replace_all(str, from, "");
}
```

I tested:

```
int main() {
    std::string str = "__+__hello__+__";
    std::cout << remove_all(str, "__+__");

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

and my output was:

```
hello
```